# Which hornet-like insect is this?

Tags: species-identification

This insect flew through my open 10th floor window, around midnight.
Its flying pretty fast for insects, and bumping into the ceiling a lot.
[image: Text]
Location: southern Germany.
For me it looks almost like a hornet, except for the eyes, which in my opinion are way to big for hornets.
The wire mesh in the background has a 12mm spacing.
Any guesses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a hornet at all, nor any Hymenoptera but rather a Diptera. As you suggest, the eyes as well as the wing structure give it away.

It looks like a horse fly, possibly [*Tabanus sudeticus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabanus_sudeticus) or [*Tabanus bovinus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabanus_bovinus) based on the large size and coloration in the abdomen.